# Scan column and row one by one before moving to another column MULTIDIMENSIONAL ARRAY C#(UNITY)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gambling

Hi I created a script that will scan the whole `Column` and `Row` the problem is that I need to scan first all the data on that specific column and then move to the next one . Here is my script

```
#region BIG EYE ROAD 
//COLUMN
int prevSum = -1;
for (int col = 0; col < table.GetLength(0); ++col)
{
    GameObject p = Instantiate(big_eye_gameobject) as GameObject;
    p.transform.SetParent(pos_big_eye_road);
    p.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

   img = (RawImage)p.GetComponent<RawImage>();

   int sum = CountRow(table, col);

   Debug.Log("How many are there : " + CountRow(table, col));
   //Debug.Log("table column :" + col + " has " + sum + " data");
   if (sum == prevSum)
   {
        if (StartingPos == 1)
        {
            BigEyeYIndex = 0;
            BigEyeXIndex = 0;
            StartingPos++;
        }
        else
        {
            BigEyeYIndex += 1;
        }

        img.texture = NewTexture[1];
        p.SetActive(true);
        //Debug.Log(col + " has the same length data as " + (col - 1));
   }
   else
   {
        BigEyeXIndex += 1;
        BigEyeYIndex = 0;
        img.texture = NewTexture[0];
        p.SetActive(true);
   }
        prevSum = sum;

   p.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(BigEyeXIndex * 56, BigEyeYIndex * -45, 0f);  
    }
    #endregion
    yield return null;

}
//generic function
public static int CountRow<T>(T[,] table, int col)
{
    if (table == null || col < 0 || col >= table.GetLength(1)) 
    {
        //handle error
        return -1;
    }

    //this is the same as the block of the outer for loop
    int sum = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < table.GetLength(1); row++)
    {
        if(table[col,row] != null)
        {
            sum++;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

What this code does is that it just scan the whole row and column.

And here i created my own data

[image]

the 2nd board depends on the output of the first board

The Starting point corresponds to cell B2 
on the 1st image above. if B2 is empty, 
the starting point is C1.

For example , the first entry shows cell A1 on the image above . Since cell B2 is the beginning of a new column, 
we check if the previous two columns are equal in length. What it means is that if cell B2 and B1 is equal of the length of A2 and A1

If they are I will mark on the 2nd board a red circle if 
different in length it would be blue.

Next entry to see is C1 on the image above. So I need to compare the length of the whole column of cell B and cell A

So they're not the same in length so it would mark it as a blue because they're different in length

Next entry to see is C2 on the image above. So I need to compare the length of cell C2 and C1 to B2 and B1 now are they the same in length? YES so i mark on the 2nd board RED

Next entry to see is C3 on the image above. So I need to compare the length of cell C3 and C2 to B3 and B2 now are they the same in length? NO so i mark on the 2nd board BLUE

Next entry to see is C4 on the image above. So I need to compare the length of cell C4 and C3 to B4 and B3 now are they the same in length? YES so i mark on the 2nd board RED . You must be confuse but even though it is NULL they are the same in length.

Next entry to see is C5 on the image above. So I need to compare the length of cell C5 and C4 to B5 and B4 now are they the same in length? YES so i mark on the 2nd board RED .

Next entry to see will be D1 the same rules as C1 it will count the whole column of cell C and cell B if they have the same length mark RED else BLUE

Next entry to see is D2 on the image above. So I need to compare the length of cell D2 and D1 to C2 and C1 now are they the same in length? YES so i mark on the 2nd board RED .

AND SO ON.

So expected output is this

[image]

The expected output is only from Cell D I didn't include the remaining cell E

I know I'm almost there with my code . But i can't figure it out. Could someone help

Here's my code on the 1st board

```
 string[] strData = { "P  ,P  ,P  ,B  ,T  ,P  ,P B,P  ,P  ,P  ,B  ,B  ,T  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,T  ,P  " };
 string[,] table = new string[104, 6];
 int xIndex = 0;
 int yIndex = 0;
 string OriginalData = "";

  IEnumerator Win_Log()
{

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    for (int i = 0; i < strData.Length; i++)
    {
        OriginalData += strData[i];
        OriginalData += ",";
    }
    string[] newNewData = OriginalData.Split(',');
    string result = "";

    string previous = "";
    int counterForTie = 0;
    int counterForRow = 1;
    int justMoveToY = 1;


    int moveRow = 1;
    int moveCol = 1;

    foreach (string newStrData in newNewData)
    {
        //Debug.Log("This is the data : " + newStrData);

        GameObject o = Instantiate(prefab_gameobject) as GameObject;
        o.transform.SetParent(pos_big_road);
        o.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

        img = (RawImage)o.GetComponent<RawImage>();

        //check the length so that it won't throw an exception
        if (newStrData.Length > 1)
        {
            //get only the first letter of the value P,B,T
            result = newStrData.Substring(0, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            result = "";
        }

        #region BIG ROAD
        if (table.GetLength(0) < xIndex)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (result.Equals(newPrevious) || result.Equals("T") && yIndex < table.GetLength(1))
        {
            if (counterForRow == 1)
            {
                yIndex = 0;
                counterForTie++;
                table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
                counterForRow++;
            }
            else
            {
                yIndex += 1;
                counterForTie++;
                table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
            }
        }
        else if (result.Equals(newPrevious) && previous.Equals("T") && yIndex < table.GetLength(1))
        {
            yIndex += 1;
            counterForTie++;
            table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
        }
        else
        {
            if (justMoveToY == 1 && counterForRow == 1)
            {
                xIndex = 0;
                yIndex = 0;
                table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
                justMoveToY++;
                counterForRow++;

            }
            else if (justMoveToY == 1)
            {
                xIndex = 0;
                yIndex += 1;
                table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
                justMoveToY++;
            }
            else
            {
                xIndex += 1;
                yIndex = 0;
                table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
                counterForTie = 0;
            }
        }

        previous = result;

        if (!result.Equals("T"))
        {
            newPrevious = previous;
        }

        if (counterForTie < 6)
        {
            o.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(xIndex * 56, yIndex * -45, 0f);
        }
        else
        {
            int reminder = counterForTie % 5;
            o.transform.localPosition = new Vector3((xIndex + reminder) * 93, -465, 0f);
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately you're probably not going to get a lot of attention to this question because it's not entirely clear what you are asking. It's a lot to ask somebody to go through your logic and try to a) figure out what you are trying to do and b) where things might have gone wrong. If you can edit _this_ question (don't delete and ask a new one) to provide a smaller sample input and show the output pointing out exactly where it is not what you are expecting that will help anyone trying to answer it.

Comment: I already got it @ColinYoung . Sorry for posting twice .